# Frequencies of bigrams in English alphabet(with space)

Tags: frequency-analysis

Does anyone know where to find bigram frequencies for English alphaber with space?

Answer (score 1):

Does http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html help?

Not sure how I can get to 30 characters for an acceptable answer length on this one... And hi.